# javafx: setRowFactory fails to detect the current state of the TableView

Tags: java, javafx

I have the following class for `setRowFactory`. The reason I am not writing this as an anonymous class is because I have multiple functions within this class and I want this class to be reusable. The functions are:

1. highlight the recently added Trade Object (entire row) in the TableView
2. Flash the "price" cell when the price property is greater than 0, where caution property becomes true.

public class Trade{

```
    private ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper caution;
     ...

    // with constructor there is 
    public Trade(){
          ...
          this.caution = new ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper();
          this.caution.bind(this.price.greaterThan(0));
    }
    ...
```

}

This works fine. **Problem occurs** when I **delete** Trade objects from the TableView. The empty rows continue to flash, which clearly means that the code is not monitoring the current state of the TableView.

I am still new to javafx and I think I am missing the `addListener` code to track the current state of all the rows within tableView (**Correct me if I am wrong.**) And I don't know how to write it out.

Code:

```
public class AnimatedTransactionLogTableRow<T> extends TableRow<T> {

    private static final PseudoClass PS_NEW = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("new-row");
    private static final PseudoClass PS_FLASH = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("flash-row");
    private static final PseudoClass PS_CF = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("cell-positive");


    private final ObjectExpression<T> recentItem;
    private final InvalidationListener recentlyAddedListener = fObs -> recentItemChanged();

    private final Function<T, BooleanExpression> flashExtractor;
    private final ChangeListener<Boolean> flashListener = (fObs, fOld, fNew) -> flasherChanged(fNew);
    private final Timeline flashTimeline;

    public AnimatedTransactionLogTableRow(ObjectExpression<T> fRecentlyAddedProperty
                                         ,Function<T, BooleanExpression> fFlashExtractor
                                        ) {
        recentItem = fRecentlyAddedProperty;
        recentItem.addListener(new WeakInvalidationListener(recentlyAddedListener));


        flashExtractor = fFlashExtractor;
        flashTimeline = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.5), e -> pseudoClassStateChanged(PS_FLASH, true)),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1.0), e -> pseudoClassStateChanged(PS_FLASH, false)));
        flashTimeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);

    }


    private void flasherChanged(boolean fNew) {
        if (fNew) {
            flashTimeline.play();
            pseudoClassStateChanged(PS_CF,true);
        } else {
            flashTimeline.stop();
            pseudoClassStateChanged(PS_FLASH, false);
            pseudoClassStateChanged(PS_CF,false);

        }
    }

    private void recentItemChanged() {
        final T tmpRecentItem = recentItem.get();
        pseudoClassStateChanged(PS_NEW, tmpRecentItem != null && tmpRecentItem == getItem());
    }


    @Override
    protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        System.out.println("getItem(): " + getItem());
        if (getItem() != null) {
            final BooleanExpression be = flashExtractor.apply(getItem());
            if (be != null) {
                be.removeListener(flashListener);
            }
        }

        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (getItem() != null) {
            final BooleanExpression be = flashExtractor.apply(getItem());
            if (be != null) {
                be.addListener(flashListener);
                flasherChanged(be.get());
            }
        }

        recentItemChanged();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi @James_D, Thanks for the comment ! Let me make an attempt to tackle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to call `flasherChanged(false);` if the `TableRow` is empty.

For example:

```
@Override
protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
    System.out.println("getItem(): " + getItem());
    if (getItem() != null) {
        final BooleanExpression be = flashExtractor.apply(getItem());
        if (be != null) {
            be.removeListener(flashListener);
        }
    }

    super.updateItem(item, empty);

    if(empty) {
        flasherChanged(false);  
    }
    else if (getItem() != null) {
        final BooleanExpression be = flashExtractor.apply(getItem());
        if (be != null) {
            be.addListener(flashListener);
            flasherChanged(be.get());
        }
    }

    recentItemChanged();
}
```